# how to insert the values into table (through model) in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

controller part:

```
def status_of_post

  post=Post.find(params[:post_id])
  user=User.find(params[:user_id])
  Post_user_status.build(user_id: user,post_id: post)
end
```

Script part:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.status').click(function () {
            var post_id = $(this).attr("id");
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "/status_of_post",
                data: {"post_id": post_id, "user_id": <%= current_user.id %>},
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('successfully');

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I need to insert the values from the ajax data to the table.what did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As a side note why do you need to send `current user id`, i mean you can direct access it at controller side even.

controller: -

```
def status_of_post
  post=Post.find(params[:post_id])
  user= current_user
  Post_user_status.build(user_id: user,post_id: post)
end
```

script part :

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.status').click(function () {
                var post_id = $(this).attr("id");
                //var current_user_id = "<%=current_user.id%>";
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/status_of_post",
                    type: "POST",
                    //data: {post_id: post_id, user_id: current_user_id},
                    data: {post_id: post_id},
                    dataType: "script",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert('successfully');

                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I have commented the line to send `current_user.id` in script code, if you really need `current_user.id` you can use it. but you can access current user directly at controller. i hope it helped you, feel free to accept/upvote answer. thank you

Comment: Accessing data is not the problem here.the problem is in the build method

Comment: whats the problem?

Comment: def status_of_post                                                                                                     
  post=Post.find(params[:post_id])    
  user= current_user
  PostUserStatus.create!(user_id: user,post_id: post)  
end                                                                                                                                                    There was a mistake. I wrongly specified model name .

Comment: hmm if my response helped you, you can upvote response. thanks :)